# Error: the method sort (Comparable []) in the type Selection is not applicable for the arguments (int[])

Tags: java, algorithm, compiler-errors

that is the error I get when trying to write out the Selection sort. Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong. My code is below. Thanks!

```
    public class Selection
    {
        static void sort(Comparable[] a)
    {
    int N = a.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
    int min = i;
     for (int j = i+1; j < N; j++)
     if (less(a[j], a[min]))
     min = j;
     exch(a, i, min);
     }
     }
     private static boolean less(Comparable v, Comparable w)
     { 
     return v.compareTo(w) < 0;   
     }
    private static void exch(Comparable[] a, int i, int j)
    { 
     Comparable temp = a[i];
     a[i] = a[j];
     a[j] = temp;
 }

public static void main(String args[])
{

    int[] ys = {3,4,5,5,22,4,66,4444,33,3,656,544,4};
    Selection.sort(ys);
}


}
```

Comment: You'll love yourself in a couple months if you learn to format your code early on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

int is a primitive type, and therefore cannot implement any interface. That's why int[] cannot be passed to a method that expects Comparable[].

You could overcome this error by changing `ys` to be an array of Integer (i.e Integer[]), since Integer implements Comparable.

Answer (score 2):

`int` is a primitive data type. It is not a class, and it doesn't implement `Comparable`

You should use [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) instead, which does implement `Comparable`.

Answer (score 0):

Comparable works with objects, and as you know an `int` is not an object.  `int[]` resolves to a `singular object` not an array of objects.

If you define `ys` as `Integer[]` then you will get your expected Array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by earlier asnwers, you can't apply `int` for `Comparable`, but if you still want to work with primitives and use `Integer` instead of `Comparable` which implements `Comparable` and the compiler will implicitly convert `int` to `Integer`:

```
static void sort(int[] a)
{
    int N = a.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        int min = i;

        for (int j = i+1; j < N; j++)
            if (less(a[j], a[min]))
                min = j;

        exch(a, i, min);
    }
}

private static boolean less(Integer v, Integer w)
{
    return v.compareTo(w) < 0;
}

private static void exch(int[] a, int i, int j)
{
    int temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
}
```